# Where to apply clearfix(es)?

Tags: css, clearfix

Top margin of first card is result of `float: right` applied on button.
If I remove that right float, top margin appears above second card. What's proper way to fix this? Where to apply clearfix(es)?

[check example on codepen](http://codepen.io/ridjis/pen/amJNpb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float: left;` to `.card` CSS class and remove `float: right;` from `.btn`

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #373a3c;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  max-width: 20rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
  float: left;
}

.card-wide {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 35rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
  
  .card-img-left {
    float: left;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  
  .card-block-wide {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    .card-title-wide {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
  }
  .btn-wide {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 180px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-block {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;  
  }
}

.card-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  small {
    &::before {
      content: "(";
    }
    &::after {
      content: ")";
    }
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #777;
  }
}

.btn {
  line-height: 1.25;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*float: right;*/
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #025aa5;
    border-color: #01549b;
  }
}

.btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #025aa5;
  border-color: #01549b;
}
.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #449d44;
    border-color: #419641;
  }
}

.btn-success:focus, .btn-success.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #449d44;
  border-color: #419641;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
      <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/c5o7FN2vzI7xlU6IF1y64mgcH9E.jpg" alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">The Prestige <small>2006</small></h4>
        <p class="card-text">
        Two stage magicians engage in competitive one-upmanship in an attempt to create the ultimate stage illusion.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Add as favourite</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-wide">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/g0Fl4pn.jpg" class="card-img-left">
      <div class="card-block-wide">
        <h4 class="card-title-wide">Inception</h4>
        <p class="card-text-wide">
        Two stage magicians engage in competitive one-upmanship in an attempt to create the ultimate stage illusion.</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn-wide btn-success">Add as favourite</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float: left` on `.card` works just fine. About `float: right` on `.btn`, I want to right align that button, so deleting that float is unnecessary.

Comment: Well! add `position: relative;  float: right;` to `.btn`